# 'Fire and forget' promises in a serverless (NextJS) environment

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, next.js, datadog

I'm adding third party logging to my nodejs app, the API has an ingestion endpoint I need to call with logging information.

The problem is that this request takes time, if I await all the logging requests it will add significant time to function executions.

My thinking was to do a 'fire and forget' approach however given NextJS will cancel all executing processes this may occasionally fail. I also found logging may arrive in a different order than sent (though this can be mediated with a timestamp).

What I'd love to do is fire off the log and ensure the request has been sent without waiting on the response from the server - is this possible?

I'm thinking to add a 1ms wait after each log since an initial http request with a small payload isn't going to take that long to send but wanted to know are their any best practices for handling these sorts of scenarios?

Comment: What do you mean by "nextjs will cancel all executing processes"?

Comment: What would your success criteria be for "ensure the request has been sent" if the code doesn't wait for a response? Can you include an example of how the code logs to the api/datadog?